# Swift 3 NSFileManager Xcode 8 Error: Has been renamed FileManager

Tags: swift3

Trying to get default documents directory in Swift 3 but says it has been renamed to FileManager.  If update to FileManager then get error:  Cannot call value of non-function type FileManager

Xcode 8. Swift 3 Beta 4.

using this line of code from [FMDB Swift Instructions](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb):

```
let documents = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
```

Comment: If it's been renamed `FileManager` then why are you using `NSFileManager`?

Comment: Tried that and it then errors:  Cannot call value of non-function type FileManager

Comment: I've updated the README accordingly, to provide both Swift 3 and Swift 2 examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

URLForDirectory has been renamed to url(for: in: appropriateFor: create: ). You have to do as follow:

```
let documents = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
```

Comment: Thankyou!! that worked but now errors on next line stating that URL has no member 'URLB yAPpendingPathComponent'  do you know what this was changed to?  
let fileURL = documents.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.sqlite")

Comment: Just use `.appendingPathComponent`